# Как вытащить текст из переменной?

Tags: python, windows, telebot, переменные

Моя проблема в том, что я хочу создать бота в тг который собирает информацию которую ввел пользователь и из этой инфы создавал URL-кнопку. У меня готов весь текст только когда я сделал переменные они равны message.text. А мне нужно запросить у пользователя 3 параметра Название сообщения название URL-кнопки и URL собственно. Помогите пожалуйста как записать или вытащить текст который ввел пользователь в мои переменные.
Вот код:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types
import schedule, time
bot = telebot.TeleBot(ТОКЕН)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(message):
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("меню отправки")
    btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("создатель")
    markup.add(btn1, btn2)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Привет!", reply_markup=markup)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def func(message):
    if(message.text == "создатель"):
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Создатель: @mipo25lvl")
    elif(message.text == "меню отправки"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Создать пост")
        back = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в меню")
        markup.add(btn3, back)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выбери действие:", reply_markup=markup)
    elif (message.text == "Вернуться в меню"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("меню отправки")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("создатель")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Вы вернулись в меню", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text="Выбери действие:", reply_markup=markup)
    elif(message.text == "Создать пост"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Написать текст сообщения")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Написать текст ссылки")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Прекрипить ссылку")
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в меню отправки")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что бы создать пост сделай действия:', reply_markup=markup)
    elif (message.text == "Вернуться в меню отправки"):
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
        btn1 = types.KeyboardButton("Написать текст сообщения")
        btn2 = types.KeyboardButton("Написать текст ссылки")
        btn3 = types.KeyboardButton("Прекрипить ссылку")
        btn4 = types.KeyboardButton("Вернуться в меню отправки")
        markup.add(btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4)
    elif (message.text == "Написать текст сообщения"):
        f = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши текст')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(f, messagetextic)
    elif (message.text == "Написать текст ссылки"):
        f = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши текст ссылки')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(f, messagetextic2)
    elif (message.text == "Прекрипить ссылку"):
        f = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Напиши ссылку в формате https://vk.com/')
        bot.register_next_step_handler(f, messagetextic3)
def messagetextic(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton('Выполни следующие действие', url='vk.com')
    markup.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text, reply_markup=markup)
def messagetextic2(message):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'{messagetextic}', url='vk.com')
    markup.add(button1)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, message.text, reply_markup=markup)
def messagetextic3(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'сделай следующие действие')
bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Пытался по всякому перерыл весь инет button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton(f'{messagetextic}', url='vk.com')так тоже не работает.